# Pivotting time series data with multiple values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several urls of sns `post`s and have been daily keeping track of its `readCount`, `likeCount`, `commentCount` etc.

This is the dataframe I got using pandas:

```
     post_url       nickname    date_key  readCount  likeCount  commentCount
5       a_url          user1  2020-06-12     2874.0        194           NaN
4       a_url          user1  2020-06-13     4030.0        208          48.0
6       a_url          user1  2020-06-14        NaN        220          48.0
7       a_url          user1  2020-06-15        NaN        223          48.0
0       b_url          user2  2020-06-13    16882.0        295          88.0
2       b_url          user2  2020-06-14        NaN        296          88.0
3       b_url          user2  2020-06-15        NaN        299          88.0
```

And the result I want to achieve is (please don't mind the actual values as they're improvised):

```
      post_url      nickname          type  2020-06-12  2020-06-13    2020-06-14  2020-06-15
5        a_url         user1     readCount      2874.0      3074.0           NaN         NaN
4        a_url         user1     likeCount      4030.0      4334.0        4888.0      7463.0
6        a_url         user1  commentCount         NaN         220          48.0        59.0
1        b_url         user2     readCount         NaN         194           NaN         NaN 
3        b_url         user2     likeCount         NaN         208          88.0       493.0
2        b_url         user2  commentCount         NaN         220          53.0       292.0
```

Note that each `post` has different subset of `date_key`s and my goal is to combine all the existing `date_key`s into columns.

I've tried searching SO regarding this topic, but I failed to find the exact same use cases.

Could you suggest a way I can achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot and then [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) for general solution for aggregation by `mean` if possible duplicates per columns `post_url,nickname,type,date_key`:

```
df = (df.melt(['post_url','nickname','date_key'], var_name='type')
        .dropna(subset=['value'])
        .pivot_table(index=['post_url','nickname','type'], 
                     columns='date_key', 
                     values='value', 
                     aggfunc='mean')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  post_url nickname          type  2020-06-12  2020-06-13  2020-06-14  \
0    a_url    user1  commentCount         NaN        48.0        48.0   
1    a_url    user1     likeCount       194.0       208.0       220.0   
2    a_url    user1     readCount      2874.0      4030.0         NaN   
3    b_url    user2  commentCount         NaN        88.0        88.0   
4    b_url    user2     likeCount         NaN       295.0       296.0   
5    b_url    user2     readCount         NaN     16882.0         NaN   

   2020-06-15  
0        48.0  
1       223.0  
2         NaN  
3        88.0  
4       299.0  
5         NaN
```

Another idea, if no aggregation necessary with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['post_url','nickname','date_key'])
        .stack()
        .unstack(2)
        .rename_axis(index=['post_url','nickname','type'], columns=None)
        .reset_index()
        )
print (df)
  post_url nickname          type  2020-06-12  2020-06-13  2020-06-14  \
0    a_url    user1     readCount      2874.0      4030.0         NaN   
1    a_url    user1     likeCount       194.0       208.0       220.0   
2    a_url    user1  commentCount         NaN        48.0        48.0   
3    b_url    user2     readCount         NaN     16882.0         NaN   
4    b_url    user2     likeCount         NaN       295.0       296.0   
5    b_url    user2  commentCount         NaN        88.0        88.0   

   2020-06-15  
0         NaN  
1       223.0  
2        48.0  
3         NaN  
4       299.0  
5        88.0
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you very much. Just a quick question: what does the `'value'` in `.dropna(subset=['value'])` refer to?

Comment: @ShinhongPark - It is new column created from `melt`, from `type`s columns.